# Custom sorting and borders in Excel

Tags: vba, sorting, excel, border

I have an Excel table that looks something like this (edited values for obvious work-related reasons, but format still applies):

(please scroll down for the things I need, and the VBA script that I made, and is not functioning correctly for some reasons - yea, I'm a beginner in scripting)

```
   A     B     C        D       E          F        G   H     I      J
XNumber Typ SBin      Bpos     SSU      Material    qty No.   C
8421017 ASD 111-A-07    1   6532378604  31814605    150 ST  154A148 
8421033 ASD 111-A-07    2   6532378605  32150251    30  ST  154A132 
8421207 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153499    25  ST  154A839 
8421108 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153495    25  ST  154A741 
8421123 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153495    25  ST  154A756 
8421112 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153495    25  ST  154A743 
8421210 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153499    25  ST  154A842 
8421116 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153495    25  ST  154A747 
8421120 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153495    25  ST  154A752 
8421128 ASD 111-A-07    3   6532414771  32153495    25  ST  154A758 
8421019 ASD 111-B-01    3   6532375593  32114883    30  ST  154A143 
8421023 ASD 111-B-04    3   6532413406  32153495    25  ST  154A134 
8421014 ASD 111-B-06    2   6532356348  32114885    30  ST  154A142 
8421009 ASD 111-B-07    1   6532391172  32114884    30  ST  154A151 
8421030 ASD 111-B-07    1   6532391172  32150249    30  ST  154A147 
8421185 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A819 
8421202 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153495    25  ST  154A835 
8421161 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A797 
8421157 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A790 
8421173 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A809 
8421177 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A812 
8421165 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A800 
8421122 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32150246    30  ST  154A757 
8421169 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A803 
8421181 ASD 111-B-07    2   6532416499  32153494    30  ST  154A817 
8421011 ASD 111-C-01    1   6532398471  32081811    300 ST  154A145 
8421114 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32150246    30  ST  154A749 
8421136 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32153495    25  ST  154A766 
8421132 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32153495    25  ST  154A764 
8421228 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32153499    25  ST  154A861 
8421118 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32150246    30  ST  154A750 
8421215 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32153499    25  ST  154A847 
8421140 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32153495    25  ST  154A772 
8421220 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32153499    25  ST  154A852 
8421224 ASD 111-C-02    2   6532414779  32153499    25  ST  154A855 
8421012 ASD 111-C-03    3   6532375624  32185577    30  ST  154A149 
8421076 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32114882    30  ST  154A710 
8421080 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32150246    30  ST  154A714 
8421086 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32150246    30  ST  154A720 
8421074 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32113181    150 ST  154A708 
8421077 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32150248    30  ST  154A711 
8421231 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32153499    25  ST  154A863 
8421233 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32153499    25  ST  154A865 
8421093 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32150246    30  ST  154A726 
8421084 ASD 111-C-04    1   6532414781  32114882    30  ST  154A717 
8421232 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A867 
8421222 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A857 
8421229 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A862 
8421238 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A871 
8421235 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A868 
8421040 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150743    30  ST  154A671 
8421218 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A850 
8421226 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A859 
8421241 ASD 111-D-01    1   6532417810  32150246    30  ST  154A876 
8421005 ASD 111-D-01    3   6532303506  32150254    30  ST  154A663 
8421216 ASD 111-D-03    3   6532417804  32150246    30  ST  154A848 
8421205 ASD 111-D-03    3   6532417804  32150246    30  ST  154A838 
8421211 ASD 111-D-03    3   6532417804  32150246    30  ST  154A844 
8421043 ASD 111-D-03    3   6532417804  32150255    30  ST  154A679 
8421090 ASD 111-D-03    3   6532417804  32114882    30  ST  154A725 
8421004 ASD 111-D-04    2   6532398452  32150254    30  ST  154A662 
8421237 ASD 111-D-05    3   6532414792  32153499    25  ST  154A870 
8421144 ASD 111-D-05    3   6532414792  32153495    25  ST  154A777 
8421190 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A825 
8421178 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A813 
8421194 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A826 
8421201 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A836 
8421162 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A795 
8421158 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A793 
8421197 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A830 
8421186 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A821 
8421166 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A798 
8421170 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A805 
8421154 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A789 
8421174 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A808 
8421182 ASD 111-D-06    3   6532416543  32150246    30  ST  154A814 
8421239 ASD 111-E-05    3   6532414797  32153499    25  ST  154A873 
8421242 ASD 111-E-05    3   6532414797  32153499    25  ST  154A875 
8421036 ASD 111-F-01    2   6532411757  32114878    30  ST  154A672 
8421013 ASD 111-F-03    3   6532408584  32012238    30  ST  154A140 
8421008 ASD 111-F-03    3   6532408584  32074861    30  ST  154A150 
8421003 ASD 111-F-03    3   6532408584  32150254    30  ST  154A126 
8421047 ASD 111-F-05    2   6532422980  32012238    30  ST  154A681 
8421183 ASD 111-F-06    1   6532414832  32153495    25  ST  154A816 
8421187 ASD 111-F-06    1   6532414832  32153495    25  ST  154A820 
8421191 ASD 111-F-06    1   6532414832  32153495    25  ST  154A823 
8421028 ASD 111-F-06    2   6532403825  32150255    30  ST  154A130 
8421221 ASD 111-F-06    3   6532417790  32153494    30  ST  154A854 
8421204 ASD 111-F-06    3   6532417790  32153494    30  ST  154A837 
8421217 ASD 111-F-06    3   6532417790  32153494    30  ST  154A853 
8421208 ASD 111-F-06    3   6532417790  32153494    30  ST  154A841 
8421225 ASD 111-F-06    3   6532417790  32153494    30  ST  154A858 
8421212 ASD 111-F-06    3   6532417790  32153494    30  ST  154A845 
8421213 ASD 111-F-06    3   6532417790  32153494    30  ST  154A849 
8421107 ASD 111-G-04    1   6532411911  32153499    25  ST  154A738 
8421111 ASD 111-G-04    1   6532411911  32153499    25  ST  154A745 
8421119 ASD 111-G-04    2   6532411913  32153499    25  ST  154A753 
8421135 ASD 111-G-04    2   6532411913  32153499    25  ST  154A769 
8421124 ASD 111-G-04    2   6532411913  32153499    25  ST  154A755 
8421127 ASD 111-G-04    2   6532411913  32153499    25  ST  154A761 
8421131 ASD 111-G-04    2   6532411913  32153499    25  ST  154A763 
8421115 ASD 111-G-04    2   6532411913  32153499    25  ST  154A748 
8421139 ASD 111-G-04    2   6532411913  32153499    25  ST  154A771 
8421091 ASD 111-G-06    1   6532411761  32153494    30  ST  154A723 
8421095 ASD 111-G-06    1   6532411761  32153494    30  ST  154A729 
8421097 ASD 111-G-06    1   6532411761  32153494    30  ST  154A733 
8421075 ASD 111-G-06    1   6532411761  32153494    30  ST  154A707 
8421083 ASD 111-G-06    1   6532411761  32153494    30  ST  154A716 
8421082 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32113181    150 ST  154A715 
8421219 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32153495    25  ST  154A851 
8421223 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32153495    25  ST  154A856 
8421227 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32153495    25  ST  154A860 
8421230 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32153495    25  ST  154A864 
8421089 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32113181    150 ST  154A722 
8421206 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32153495    25  ST  154A840 
8421209 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32153495    25  ST  154A843 
8421214 ASD 111-G-06    3   6532416505  32153495    25  ST  154A846 
8421020 ASD 111-G-07    1   6532414831  31983630    20  ST  154A139 
8421035 ASD 111-G-07    1   6532414831  31983630    20  ST  154A666 
8421179 ASD 111-G-07    1   6532414831  32153495    25  ST  154A810 
8421018 ASD 111-G-07    1   6532414831  31850999    30  ST  154A137 
8421026 ASD 111-H-04    1   6532411763  32150250    30  ST  154A129 
8421031 ASD 111-H-05    1   6532392763  32150252    30  ST  154A146 
8421038 ASD 111-H-05    1   6532392763  32150256    30  ST  154A674 
8421029 ASD 111-H-05    1   6532392763  31814606    250 ST  154A152 
8421015 ASD 111-H-05    1   6532392763  32150256    30  ST  154A141 
8421041 ASD 111-H-06    2   6532411917  32150250    30  ST  154A678 
8421134 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32150246    30  ST  154A768 
8421200 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32153494    30  ST  154A833 
8421130 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32150246    30  ST  154A765 
8421189 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32153494    30  ST  154A822 
8421138 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32150246    30  ST  154A770 
8421142 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32150246    30  ST  154A775 
8421193 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32153494    30  ST  154A829 
8421126 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32150246    30  ST  154A759 
8421146 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32150246    30  ST  154A780 
8421150 ASD 111-H-07    2   6532416534  32150246    30  ST  154A785 
8421247 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A880 
8421248 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A881 
8421245 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A877 
8421243 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A874 
8421249 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A882 
8421234 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A866 
8421236 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A869 
8421057 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  31983630    20  ST  154A695 
8421065 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  31983630    20  ST  154A699 
8421240 ASD 111-H-07    3   6532416523  32153495    25  ST  154A872 
8421053 ASD 111-I-03    1   6532411919  32150250    30  ST  154A687 
8421025 ASD 111-I-04    1   6532411924  32153499    25  ST  154A133 
8421034 ASD 111-I-07    1   6532411888  32012238    30  ST  154A668 
8421098 ASD 111-I-07    2   6532414829  32150246    30  ST  154A732 
8421106 ASD 111-I-07    2   6532414829  32150246    30  ST  154A739 
8421068 ASD 111-I-07    2   6532414829  32114882    30  ST  154A701 
8421073 ASD 111-I-07    2   6532414829  32150246    30  ST  154A704 
8421102 ASD 111-I-07    2   6532414829  32150246    30  ST  154A734 
8421110 ASD 111-I-07    2   6532414829  32150246    30  ST  154A742 
8421195 ASD 111-I-07    3   6532414834  32153495    25  ST  154A827 
8421198 ASD 111-I-07    3   6532414834  32153495    25  ST  154A831 
8421016 ASD 111-J-04    1   6532411934  32114878    30  ST  154A138 
8421064 ASD 111-J-04    1   6532411934  32150250    30  ST  154A697 
8421069 ASD 111-J-04    1   6532411934  32150250    30  ST  154A705 
8421085 ASD 111-J-04    2   6532411935  32150250    30  ST  154A718 
8421092 ASD 111-J-04    2   6532411935  32150250    30  ST  154A724 
8421022 ASD 111-J-04    2   6532411935  32150743    30  ST  154A131 
8421078 ASD 111-J-04    2   6532411935  32150250    30  ST  154A713 
8421067 ASD 111-J-04    3   6532411936  32153499    25  ST  154A154A    
8421079 ASD 111-J-04    3   6532411936  32153499    25  ST  154A709 
8421087 ASD 111-J-04    3   6532411936  32153499    25  ST  154A719 
8421039 ASD 111-J-04    3   6532411936  32153499    25  ST  154A669 
8421054 ASD 111-J-04    3   6532411936  32153499    25  ST  154A686 
8421070 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32113181    150 ST  154A706 
8421246 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153499    25  ST  154A879 
8421147 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A781 
8421171 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A802 
8421155 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A786 
8421167 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A799 
8421175 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A806 
8421052 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  31983630    20  ST  154A684 
8421151 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A782 
8421244 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153499    25  ST  154A878 
8421160 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A792 
8421164 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32153495    25  ST  154A796 
8421062 ASD 111-J-05    2   6532414827  32113181    150 ST  154A696 
8421055 ASD 111-J-07    3   6532419615  32150743    30  ST  154A688 
8421042 ASD 111-K-02    3   6532411892  32153494    30  ST  154A675 
8421024 ASD 111-K-02    3   6532411892  32153494    30  ST  154A135 
8421051 ASD 111-L-01    1   6532411938  32153494    30  ST  154A685 
8421103 ASD 111-L-01    1   6532411938  32153499    25  ST  154A735 
8421099 ASD 111-L-01    1   6532411938  32153499    25  ST  154A731 
8421094 ASD 111-L-01    1   6532411938  32153499    25  ST  154A727 
8421059 ASD 111-L-01    1   6532411938  32153494    30  ST  154A694 
8421066 ASD 111-L-01    1   6532411938  32153494    30  ST  154A700 
8421203 ASD 111-L-03    1   6532413444  32153499    25  ST  154A834 
8421021 ASD 111-L-03    1   6532413444  32113181    150 ST  154A136 
8421101 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A737 
8421109 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A744 
8421129 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A762 
8421153 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A788 
8421141 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A774 
8421117 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A751 
8421104 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153495    25  ST  154A736 
8421125 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A760 
8421137 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A773 
8421113 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A746 
8421149 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A784 
8421105 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A740 
8421100 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153495    25  ST  154A730 
8421121 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A754 
8421133 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A767 
8421145 ASD 111-L-03    2   6532413446  32153494    30  ST  154A778 
8421180 ASD 111-L-03    3   6532413410  32153499    25  ST  154A811 
8421176 ASD 111-L-03    3   6532413410  32153499    25  ST  154A807 
8421184 ASD 111-L-04    2   6532413418  32153499    25  ST  154A815 
8421037 ASD 111-L-04    2   6532413418  32113181    150 ST  154A670 
8421199 ASD 111-L-04    2   6532413418  32153499    25  ST  154A832 
8421050 ASD 111-L-04    2   6532413418  32113181    150 ST  154A683 
8421192 ASD 111-L-04    2   6532413418  32153499    25  ST  154A824 
8421188 ASD 111-L-04    2   6532413418  32153499    25  ST  154A818 
8421196 ASD 111-L-04    2   6532413418  32153499    25  ST  154A828 
8421027 ASD 111-L-05    1   6532413420  32150248    30  ST  154A127 
8421007 ASD 111-L-05    1   6532413420  32150254    30  ST  154A665 
8421010 ASD 111-L-05    1   6532413420  32114882    30  ST  154A144 
8421045 ASD 111-L-05    1   6532413420  32150248    30  ST  154A677 
8421006 ASD 111-L-05    2   6532413393  32150254    30  ST  154A664 
8421096 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153495    25  ST  154A728 
8421148 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A779 
8421152 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A783 
8421046 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153495    25  ST  154A676 
8421143 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A776 
8421081 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153495    25  ST  154A712 
8421060 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153495    25  ST  154A689 
8421072 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153495    25  ST  154A702 
8421088 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153495    25  ST  154A721 
8421168 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A801 
8421172 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A804 
8421156 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A787 
8421159 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A791 
8421163 ASD 111-L-06    1   6532413380  32153499    25  ST  154A794 
8421049 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32150246    30  ST  154A680 
8421058 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32114878    30  ST  154A691 
8421063 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32150246    30  ST  154A693 
8421044 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32114882    30  ST  154A673 
8421048 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32114878    30  ST  154A682 
8421032 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32150246    30  ST  154A128 
8421056 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32114882    30  ST  154A690 
8421061 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32150248    30  ST  154A692 
8421071 ASD 111-L-06    3   6532413424  32150248    30  ST  154A703
```

I would please like to ask help with a VBA script that would do the following:

1. Sort all the table (select all cells with a value - including column J, which is used by the workers, but is empty), and only sort ascending by "Material" (column F), rearranging rows as necessary, making sure that the qty values won't be summed - I need the same number of lines after the sorting.
2. After the sorting is done, I need a script to start analyzing the table, and make a border around each of the same material. Or, if it's simpler, analyze from line 1, and, if the following value on the J column of the next line is any different (or empty), do a Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick

The VBA script I came up with is the following (sorting is not working, it sums up quantities, which is not good, and also sorts by SBin as well somehow).
The borders script omits putting borders (after I sort the whole table by Material) under the first row (since the 2nd row is of a different value), and also omits putting a border under the last row, where the next row's cell would be empty.

Please assist me, any help would be greatly appreciated.

VBA code follows:

```
Sub AddBorders()

    ' define stuff
    Dim bottomN As Integer
    bottomN = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' border all
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Weight = xlThin
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    End With

    ' convert to numbers
    Range("A:A").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Range("D:D").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Range("E:E").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Range("F:F").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Range("I:I").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With


    ' sorting --- not working as intented yet
    'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    'ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("F1:F" & bottomN) _
    '    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    '    xlSortTextAsNumbers
    'With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    '    .SetRange Range("F1:F" & bottomN)
    '    .Header = xlYes
    '    .MatchCase = False
    '    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    '    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    '    .Apply
    'End With

    ' start thick borders
    Dim startRow As Integer
    Dim iRow As Integer
    startRow = 1
    For iRow = 2 To ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(iRow - 1, 6)) Then
            If Cells(iRow, 6) <> Cells(iRow - 1, 6) Then
               AddBorder startRow, iRow - 1
               startRow = iRow
            End If
        Else
               AddBorder startRow, iRow
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
Sub AddBorder(startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer)
    Dim borderRange As Range
    Dim randomColor As Integer
    randomColor = Int((56 * Rnd) + 1)
    ' tweaked for the same row borders
    Set borderRange = Range("A" & endRow & ":J" & endRow)

    'borderRange.BorderAround ColorIndex:=0, Weight:=xlThick
    borderRange.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThick
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance. It means a lot to me if I could get this sorted with your help.

- David.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also would need to make all the rows with a value from columns A to J "border all" but the script I made does that without problems.

Comment: Your question is incredibly long-winded and that makes it quite difficult to understand what exactly you're asking here. Could you trim it down by removing salutations ("Thanks in advance", "please assist me" etc.) and reducing your huge block of data if possible? I don't see any reason you need that 100-line-or-so example table when 3 or 4 lines would probably be enough. I'd edit it myself but it would probably be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done it this way:

```
' define stuff
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'never like to use "Active" option. it is much much better to precisely define your workbook and worksheets

Dim bottomN As Integer
bottomN = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

' border all
ws.UsedRange.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

With ws.Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("F2"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:I248")
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

' start thick borders
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer
startRow = 1
For iRow = 2 To bottomN
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(iRow - 1, 6).Value) = True Then
        If StrComp(CStr(Cells(iRow, 6)), CStr(Cells(iRow - 1, 6))) <> 0 Then
           AddBorder startRow, iRow - 1
           startRow = iRow
        End If
    Else
           AddBorder startRow, iRow
    End If
Next iRow
```

Answer (score 0):

Script for Sorting

```
Sub Macro1()

    Range("A1:J" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range_
        ("F1:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues,     Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!

I took the sorting script that izzymo made and some of the script that PolaEla made and managed to finish the script and make it do what I needed.

Thank you very much for your help!